# What should I pay attention to when optimizing the spark task, in order to avoid excessive local logs generated

Tags: apache-spark

According to log analysis, the reason for restarting my EMR yarn resourcemanager is NPE crash caused by abnormal disk failure of yarn node.

What should I pay attention to when optimizing the spark task, in order to avoid excessive local logs generated by the task during the running process, which will cause the node to be marked as unhealthy, which will cause abnormal conditions.

Or what parameters should I adjust to reduce the logs that are kept locally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify `spark.history.fs.cleaner.maxAge` and `spark.history.fs.cleaner.interval` to clean up file system.
More info here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/core-node-emr-cluster-disk-space/